# Is there a stable linear shift invariant system whose transfer function is $H(z) = z^*$

Tags: discrete-signals, z-transform, stability, proof

I couldn't find such a system but I have also not been able to prove otherwise.

Firstly, I don't know exactly how to take the inverse Z-Transform of $z^*$.

Secondly, I don't know the ROC associated with it so there has to be more than one discrete-time function that has the Z-Transform, $z^*$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, there is no such stable LTI system which has an impulse response with $\mathrm{Z}$-Transform = $z^*$.

**Proof by contradiction:**

*Assume* that there is an LTI system which is BIBO stable and has the transfer function: $H(z) = z^*$.

Since $H(z)$ is stable, $|z|=1$ is inside its ROC. Therefore taking $z=e^{j\omega}$,

\begin{align*}
   H(e^{j\omega}) & = (e^{j\omega})^* = e^{-j\omega}\\
   H(e^{j\omega}) & = \text{DTFT} \{h[n]\}
\end{align*}

The $\text{IDTFT}\{e^{-j\omega}\} = \delta[n-1]$.

Then $H(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} h[n]z^{-n} = \delta[n-1]z^{-n} = z^{-1}$

But $z^{-1} \neq z^{*}$. This is a contradiction!

Therefore, there is no stable LTI system whose transfer function is $z^{*}$.

Comment: *//"But $z^{-1} \neq z^{*}$. This is a contradiction!"//* - - - - - - - How is that the case?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Write $z$ in polar form: $$z= re^{j\omega}$$ then $$z^{-1}=\frac 1z = \frac 1r e^{-j\omega}$$ The case when $r=1$ is a special case for which the equality holds.

Comment: And that's the answer to my question.  I would say it as:  *But* $z^{-1} \neq z^{*}$ *for* $|z| \ne 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the transfer function of a system with impulse response $h[n]$ is defined by

$$H(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}h[n]z^{-n}\tag{1}$$

Eq. $(1)$ is also called the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of $h[n]$.

If you look at $(1)$, it should be clear that there's no way you could ever create a transfer function $H(z)=z^*$. Stability is totally unrelated. There exists neither a stable nor an unstable system with transfer function $H(z)=z^*$.

In more mathematical terms, $H(z)=z^*$ is not an analytic function, and hence it can't be the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of any sequence. Similarly, the functions $H(z)=|z|$ or $H(z)=\textrm{Re}\{z\}$ are no valid transfer functions because they are not analytic.

Comment: *//" If you look at $(1)$, it should be clear that there's no way you could ever create a transfer function $H(z)=z^*$. "//* - - - - - - Well, it looks like one can where, on the z-plane $|z|=1$.  But I don't think the ROC remains inside the unit circle.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: But what choice of coefficients $h[n]$ in (1) could ever result in $H(z)=z^*$?

Comment: Matt L it would only match on the unit circle.  $h[n]=\delta[n-1]$.